# Abelianization of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group, $N$ a normal subgroup and $(A,\rho)$ an abelianization of $G$. Let $B=\rho(N)$ and $\lambda:G/N\to A/B$ be given by $\lambda(gN)=\rho(g)B$.

I want to show that $(A/B,\lambda)$ is an abelianization of $G/N$ (In this problem abelianization is meant in the sence of universal property)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: No one can help me please?

Comment: What is abilization $(A,\rho)$ of $G$?

Comment: i meant abelianizatio, sorry

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is this one: the abelianiztion of a group $G$ is a pair $(A,\rho)$, where $A$ is an Abelian group and $\rho\colon G\longrightarrow A$ is a group homomorphism, such that, for every homomorphism $f$ from $G$ into an Abelian group $H$, there is one and only one homomorphism $\overline f\colon A\longrightarrow H$ such that $f=\overline f\circ\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a homomorphism from $G/N$ into an abelian group $H$ and let $\pi\colon G\longrightarrow G/N$ be the natural projection. Then $f\circ\pi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ into $H$. Therefore, there's a homomorphism $f^\star\colon A\longrightarrow H$ such that $f^\star\circ\rho=f\circ\pi$. If $b\in B$, then $b=\rho(n)$ for some $n\in N$ and therefore,$$f^\star(b)=f^\star\bigl(\rho(n)\bigr)=f\bigl(\pi(n)\bigr)=f(e_{G/N})=e_H.$$So, $f^\star$ induces a homomorphism $\overline f\colon A/B\longrightarrow H$ and $\overline f\circ\lambda=f$, because, if $g\in G$,\begin{align}\overline f\bigl(\lambda(gN)\bigr)&=\overline f\bigl(\rho(g)B\bigr)\\&=f^\star\bigl(\rho(g)\bigr)\\&=f\bigl(\pi(g)\bigr)\\&=f(gN).\end{align}

Comment: and where did you use $\lambda$?

Comment: I didn't notice that you called it $\lambda$. I called it $\rho^\star$.

Comment: I have an other quetion that i can't answer, please help me if you can:

let $G$ a group. I want to show that 

$\phi(G/\phi(G))=\left\{e\phi(G)\right\}$


Where $\phi(G)$ is the  Frattini subgroup (i.e the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$)

Comment: Please post it as a question.

Comment: i post it here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426702/morphism-and-group?noredirect=1#comment5012383_2426702

Comment: @naima I've put $\lambda$ in place of $\rho^\star$.

Comment: for the other question i didn't find the answer yet, can you please help me?

Comment: @naima It's impossible, Your question was closed and nobody can answer a closed question.

Comment: In fact i have reached the limit question and i can't post any other question